# Docker bash: ng: command not found (Angular)

Tags: angular, docker

I try to run my container which contains angular but it crashes when I start docker-compose start and I get the following error:
[image]

Here is my Dockerfile.angular

```
FROM node:v16.10-alpine
ARG DEV_EMAIL
ARG DEV_NAME
ARG NODE_APP_ARG=node-app
ENV NODE_APP $NODE_APP_ARG
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN sh -c "apk add git bash && git config --global user.email \"${DEV_EMAIL}\" && git config --global user.name \"${DEV_NAME}\" && npm install -g 
@angular/cli"
EXPOSE 4200
```

this is my docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  angular:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.angular
      args:
        DEV_NAME: ${DEV_NAME}
        DEV_EMAIL: ${DEV_EMAIL}
        NODE_APP_ARG: ${NODE_APP}
    command: bash -c "( [ \"$$(ls -A)\" ] && echo \"App already made\" || ng new ${NODE_APP} --style=scss --routing=true --strict=true ) && cd /usr/src/app/${NODE_APP} && npm start"
    ports:
      - 4201:4200
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    # volumes:
    #   - ./app/nodejs:/usr/src/app
    environment:
      NODE_APP: ${NODE_APP}
      MYSQL_HOST: mysql
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 
      MYSQL_DB: ${APP_DB}
```

Comment: It seems like `@angular/cli` is not installed or if installed it is installed somewhere else your command is running somewhere else. Try installing `cli` globally.

Comment: Which command is executed in that container? You need to include your `docker-compose.yml` to make the issue replicable.

Comment: @acran i already posted my docker-compose.yml for your reference

Comment: @ShariffuddinHussin please check your setup again. The example files you provided are working perfectly fine and your error is not reproducible with them. Except that the image `node:v16.10-alpine` does not exist (on the official docker hub) and has to be changed to `node:16.10-alpine`. If this is not a typo you are using a completely different base image which may do things quite differently but which we can not debug for you then.

Answer (score 0):

You don't put anything in your docker container.

That means it's a pristine alpine distro with nothing else in it.

Try using the `COPY` command like so

```
COPY . .
```

This should put all of your files into the docker container.

Also, do not install the CLI globally. Instead, use the `RUN` command like so

```
RUN npm i
```

Which will install your dependencies, then you can run this

```
CMD ['npx', 'ng', 'serve']
```

I strongly advise you to learn more about docker before using it. It may seem simple, but it's not !